# Simple operator to access property in Fsharp

Tags: ruby, f#, operators

Is there an operator akin to symbol_to_proc in ruby ( &:symbol ) where

```
#Toto
```

is equivalent to

```
(fun x -> x.Toto)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, but you could do something like:

```
let (!?) p (x:obj) =
    x.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(x)

let four = !?"Length" [5..8]
```

This uses reflection, so it's not nearly as efficient as `[5..8].Length`, but it might give you the expressiveness you're looking for.

Comment: This is really missing in the langage, in my pov. in ruby it goes namelist.map(&:length). very succinct.

Comment: @Nicolas - undoubtedly there are times when it would be nice to avoid the explicit lambda.  Of course, if you were to use let-bound functions instead of properties, then you can do that (e.g. `namelist |> List.map length`).

Comment: As Keith said, no, there is no syntax for this; it would be nice.

Comment: @Nicolas Just a thought--perhaps you should try to learn F# on its own terms rather than dispairing about features that other languages have that you think it lacks.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I am all for learning Fsharp.  But when I can cut noisy code, I cut noisy code.  And if I knew who to contact to request such a feature I would certainly do so.

Comment: @nicolas It's just that I've noticed a pattern to your questions--you seem to want to relate everything in F# to something you already know. You asked about equivalents to "melt" and "cast" from R, for example. I would suggest that you would be far better served to learn the language on its own terms. Just my experience as a developer who has learned a few different languages over the years.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I am all for it as well. better work with the langage than against. but when you think of how langage evolves, it is mostly by taking what other langages are doing best. R is an old langage which was quite messy before some people like Hadley introduced real programming approach and betterment through functional programming, for instance.

Comment: btw, melt and cast are very cool. with baked-in strong typed support that f# handles so well, it would be dynamite.

Comment: I would love a feature like this in F#. One of the necessary warts in F# is the lambda syntax and not having to do all that (fun x -> x.member) stuff for simple property/field access would be awesome. Why 'items |> Seq.sumBy (fun item -> item.Prop)' when 'items |> Seq.sumBy #Prop' would be sufficient?

Comment: Feature suggestions go here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30935-languages-f-

Answer (score 1):

kvb's solution is the only one that'll work for the general case (where you want to be able to specify the property name at runtime).

However, if you know the name of property at compile-time and you also want to *require* that the property is present on any input, you can use an F# static constraint like so:

```
// Define the 'toto' operator
let inline toto (a : ^a) =
    (^a : (member Toto: string with get) (a))

type MyType () =
    member __.Toto with get () = "Toto"

// Create an instance of MyType
let t = MyType()

printf "The song is 'Africa', by %s" (toto t)
```